# Is my scope incorrect?

Tags: lua, scope, love2d

So I'm making a game with Love2D, and I'm getting the following error:

```
maps/map_one.lua:249: attempt to index field 'player' (a nil value)
Traceback
maps/map_one.lua:249: in function 'updateWorld'
main.lua:53: in function 'update'
```

So when I take a look at my `player`,

```
function love.load()
    ....
    objects = {}
    objects.player = {} --obviously not nil
    objects.player.body = love.physics.newBody(world, 32, 32, "dynamic")
    ...
end
```

and where the error is,

```
function updateWorld(dt)
    world:update(dt) --calculates physics and whatnot
    ....
    --line with error
    camera:setPosition(objects.player.body:getX() - (love.graphics.getWidth() / 2),
        objects.player.body:getY() - (love.graphics.getHeight() / 2))
end
```

Then I took a look at `main.lua`

```
require("maps.map_one") --file with error
....
function love.update(dt)
    updateWorld(dt) --updateWorld() in map_one.lua
end
```

I can't see anything wrong.

If it helps, I'm using Love2D v. 0.9.0 and whatever version of Lua comes with it (standalone).

Comment: Probably, global `objects` was shadowed by some local variable `objects` (e.g., which holds objects counter) inside `updateWorld`?

Answer (score 1):

The `objects.player` is not nil initially but it is nil during some update() so something is nilling it. I've never used Love2D but `love.update(dt)` takes a time step so assuming this function gets called at every time frame, you could try printing `objects.player` and see when it becomes nil:

```
function love.update(dt)
    print("objects.player:", objects.player)
    updateWorld(dt) --updateWorld() in map_one.lua
end
```

If you see some prints where `objects.player` is not nil, then it becomes nil, you know that some other update function (perhaps an event handler) is doing something to it. If it is nil even at first update then perhaps the code is doing something during initialization, after the lines you have listed in `love.load()`. You should probably `print("objects.player:", objects.player)` at the end of that function too, just to make sure it is not nil on return.